# Help me to understand combinations, please!

Tags: probability

Here is a sample question: what is the probability of rolling 3 exactly twice from an experiment wherein a 6-sided dice is rolled 5 times?

So the answer is (5C2(1/6)^2(5/6)^3)/(6^5), I think. 5C2 represents the number of ways 2 successes can be chosen from 5 runs, but I'm having trouble understanding the theory "under the hood." Can someone walk me through it?

Comment: Probability of rolling 3 precisely 1st two rolls is $(1/6)^2(5/6)^3$. But there are, as you say, $_5C_2$ ways to choose two successes from five runs, so multiply by $_5C_2$. The $6^5$ in your question is not right.

Answer (score 1):

$\binom{5}{2}$ counts the number of different ways to choose 2 objects from 5 where the order does not matter, e.g., $(A,B) = (B,A)$. Take a look at this enumeration and think of X as rolling a 3:

```
A B C D E
X X - - -
X - X - -
X - - X -
X - - - X
- X X - -
- X - X -
- X - - X
- - X X -
- - X - X
- - - X X
```

For each row in the table above, only two $3$s are rolled. The probability of rolling a $3$ is $1/6$ and the probability of not rolling a $3$ is $1-1/6=5/6$. Therefore we add of the probability of each possible trial, each of which is $(1/6)^2(5/6)^3$, and we see that there are $\binom{5}{2}$ different trials. Therefore the probability of this event is
$$
\binom{5}{2}(1/6)^2(5/6)^3.
$$

Answer (score 0):

In your attempt at the answer, the (1/6)^2 shouldn't be there at all, and the (5/6)^3 should just be 5^3.  So the answer is (5C2*5^3)/(6^5). Think of it this way:  you roll the die 5 times, you get a sequence of 5 digits, each one of 1 through 6.  When counting all such sequences, you get 6^5, the denominator.  How many of those sequences have exactly two 3's?  To count this, first select two positions in the 5-digit sequence where the 3's will appear.  There are 5C2(=10) ways to make this selection -- indicating a position to be a 3 with "+" and a position to get some other digit with "-", the possibilities are:

++---, +-+--, +--+-, +---+, -++--, -+-+-, -+--+, --++-, --+-+, and ---++

Once you know where the 3's will go, there is only one way to place the 3's.  That just leaves filling in the other three places in the sequence.  Since you want the sequence to have exactly two 3's, the remaining places must be chosen from the digits 1, 2, 4, 5, or 6 -- 5 possibilities.  There are 5^3 ways to place those digits in the remaining three places in the sequence.  So there are a total of 5C2*5^3 sequences with exactly two 3's.  The probability of getting exactly two 3's in 5 rolls of a die is (5C2*5^3)/(6^5), the number of sequences with exactly two 3's divided by the total number of sequences.
[Sorry, had to edit, forgot my markdown for a second..]